# How to justify the validity of using L'Hopital's rule in this question?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function  who is derivative on $(a,+\infty)$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty } (f(x)+f'(x)) = k$, where $k$ is finite or $\infty$. Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=k$.

 By  L'Hopital's rule, we have 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}=\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=k$$
In order to use L'Hopital's rule in the second equation, it is supposed that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}e^xf(x)=\infty$, but I can't prove it. I've tried to prove that $f(x)$is bounded on $(a,+\infty)$, but failed. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For using L'Hopital's rule, only denominator needs to diverge, not necessarily numerator.

See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Quoting from that article,

> In case $2$ $  \big(\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} |g(x)| = \infty \big)$  we did not use the assumption that $f(x)$ diverges to infinity within the proof. This means that if $|g(x)|$ diverges to infinity as $x$ approaches $c$ and both $f$ and $g$ satisfy the hypotheses of L'Hôpital's rule, then no additional assumption is needed about the limit of $f(x)$: It could even be the case that the limit of $f(x)$ does not exist. In this case, L'Hopital's theorem is actually a consequence of Cesàro–Stolz <sup>$13$</sup>.

Comment: Is it again the case that someone who doesn't actually know L'Hospital's rule is downvoting? Happened to me before. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form), downvoter, educate yourself.

Comment: I see. I really need to go over the proof of L'Hopital's rule again！